# WPF scrollviewer disabling scrollbar

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, scrollviewer

Hi I'm using wrappanel inside a scrollbar but the problem is how can I disable Horizontal scrollbar in the scrollviewer and only scroll it vertically only.
Thanks
(P.S: I'm not talking about visibility)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HorizontalScrollBarVisibility of ScrollViewer is of type `ScrollBarVisibility` (enum).

When it is set to `Disabled`, a scrollBar does not appear even if the ScrollViewer can not display all of the content.

so

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
```